# "Unexpected token" using JSONP with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use JSONP because if i use $http.get I have the XMLHttpRequest error. This is my code:

```
 .controller("showbusCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {

    var url = "http://m.aucorsa.es/inc/json/lineas.json";
    var urlJsonp = "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

   $http.jsonp (url + urlJsonp)
    .success(function(data) {
        this.lineas = lineas.data;
    });
});
```

Any solution? Thank you!

Comment: `$.getJSON('http://m.aucorsa.es/inc/json/lineas.json', function(data){
    //do something
})`  Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nqsgm0f0/

Comment: Is your JSON/p correct?

Comment: This server doesn't support JSONP, it basically ignores `callback` param.